# Check if the user is moving the map in Bing Maps

Tags: wpf, events, bing-maps, zooming, panning

I'm trying to work with Bing Maps in WPF, but everything is confusing as searching online leads me to false hope. I'll search for something, but get the AJAX version instead of the WPF version. If anyone can point me to proper documentation or help with this issue then I will be forever in their debt.

I have a map in my WPF app that I would like to track when a user is scrolling. I tried tying the map to the DragEnter event, but that didn't do anything. My question is if there is an event that I can use to check if the user is panning or zooming through the map?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to know if the Map's center is changing and if the ZoomLevel is changing? or do you really just need to know if the user is panning and scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `ViewChangeOnFrame` seems to do what you want.
See [Handing Map Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868035.aspx)

```
<m:Map ViewChangeOnFrame="MyMap_ViewChangeOnFrame" ...>
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868035.aspx)

> Assuming you have a TextBlock element named CurrentPosition defined in
>   the XAML design code, you can track the current position of a map view
>   while it is animating between locations. This code tracks the
>   position, in latitude and longitude, of the northwest and southeast
>   corners of the bounded map view.

```
void MyMap_ViewChangeOnFrame(object sender, MapEventArgs e)
{
    //Gets the map that raised this event
    Map map = (Map) sender;
    //Gets the bounded rectangle for the current frame
    LocationRect bounds = map.BoundingRectangle;
    //Update the current latitude and longitude
    CurrentPosition.Text += String.Format("Northwest: {0:F5}, Southeast: {1:F5} (Current)",
                bounds.Northwest, bounds.Southeast);
}
```